# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'

Tags: android

I get this error message when I build my app

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read path 'C:\Users\Abdullah.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\322973851a21411e089a9e85629c04f5\aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows'.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
        buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: see this link :     https://github.com/orYoffe/create-react-native-web-app/issues/10

Comment: gooogle() is already coded

Comment: Does 'C:\Users\Abdullah.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\322973851a21411e089a9e85629c04f5\aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows' exist? I'm suspicious about "Abdullah.gradle" - it should be "Abdullah/.gradle". Did you customize your gradle cache location?

Comment: Navigating to "Build -> Clean project" helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the jCenter() repository.
according to the official google documentation, you will need to manually change the location of your project dependencies.

Steps:

1. Remove jCenter() in `build.gradle` (file project) inside the buildScript -> repositories and add `mavenCentral()`

buildscript

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // New line
        jcenter() //remove that line
    }
```

2. You should do the same in `allprojects`

   ```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // New line
        jcenter() //remove that line
       // NOTE: Keep any other entries you may have had here
    }
   ```
3. Sync the project

You can find more about here on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration)

Answer (score 0):

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

make sure to place this at the very bottom of `android/app/build.gradle`, just do that for `react native` `0.60+` versions

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    ....
    ....
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

1. You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands
2. `npm install` //to get the node module folder
3. `npx react-native upgrade` //to get android and ios folder
4. `mpx react-native link` // for linking the libraries
5. `npx react-native run android/ios`

Answer (score 0):

Given a file missing from the gradle cache, you can use the name and version to find the appropriate aapt2 windows jar file by:

- Searching for `aapt2` at [maven.google.com](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=aapt2#com.android.tools.build:aapt2)
- Selecting the appropriate version under `aapt2` (e.g.
  [8.0.0-9289358](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=aapt2#com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.0.0-9289358))
- Looking at the links shown under Artifact(s) -
  one of them should be the filename you need e.g.
  [aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-windows.jar](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.0.0-9289358/aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-windows.jar)

You can download this file and place it in the directory mentioned under `.gradle\caches`; you will probably need to create the directory mentioned in the error message, for example:

- `mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\aapt2\8.0.0-9289358\3e7ac1fc0862cf8944e91f29b262f582d255af5\"`

(Note: I had this error despite not using an out-of-date repository. I had removed the `.gradle\caches` directory to check a clean build, but a clean build got stuck not finding the aapt2 jar file)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to remove

```
jcenter()
```

and add:

```
mavenCentral()
google()
```

according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html